# Using a HTML5 canvas animation as a background

Tags: html, animation, canvas, background

I'm new to HTML5 and I'd like some help adapting this particular code: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-canvas-snow-effect to be used as a background for a webpage. I've got the snow falling but when I use it as a background, nothing else displays.

Comment: You might want to show some of your code to help folks here find what's wrong with it

Answer (score 2):

You can use z-index with a value of -1 on it:

```
#myCanvas {
    position: fixed; /* or absolute */
    z-index: -1;     /* put it behind all other elements */
    }
```

Comment: +1 That's what I get for listening to a webinar while simultaneously trying to answer an SO question!

Answer (score 1):

Made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/a05zvtkw/1/) to have something to work with. As others stated, `position: fixed;` and `z-index: -1;` for the canvas works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...
*CSS*

```
#myCanvas
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1; //optional.. Depends if you have used z-index for any other element
}
```

Hope it helps someone...!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as well. For future reference to manipulate the z-index you are required to also set the position to absolute or it will not work.

```
#canvas {
    background: #202020;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```